# How do I make a UIAlertView appear only once, at the first start-up of an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, uialertview

I'm using the `UIAlertView` to make a pop-up happen once the app has started up. It works fine but I only want the pop up to appear on the first start-up of the app. At the moment I've got the `UIAlertView` in the `AppDelegate` class, in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method. Here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
sleep(4);
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome!" message:@"SAMPLE!!!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

I'm new to app development so sorry if this is simple.

Answer (score 10):

To determine whether the app is run the first time, you need to have a persistent variable to store this info. [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is the best way to store these simple configuration values.

For example,

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application … {
    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (! [defaults boolForKey:@"notFirstRun"]) {
      // display alert...
      [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"notFirstRun"];
    }
    // rest of initialization ...
}
```

Here, `[defaults boolForKey:@"notFirstRun"]` reads a boolean value named `notFirstRun` from the config. These values are initialized to NO. So if this value is NO, we execute the `if` branch and display the alert.

After it's done, we use `[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"notFirstRun"]` to change this boolean value to YES, so the `if` branch will never be executed again (assume the user doesn't delete the app).

Answer (score 4):

```
- (void) displayWelcomeScreen
{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *alreadyRun = @"already-run";
    if ([prefs boolForKey:alreadyRun])
        return;
    [prefs setBool:YES forKey:alreadyRun];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
        initWithTitle:@"…"
        message:@"…"
        delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a NSUserDefault which is initially set to 0 and which you set to 1 after showing the alert for the first time.

```
//default value is 0
[settings registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"HAVE_SHOWN_REMINDER"]];
    BOOL haveShownReminder = [settings boolForKey:@"HAVE_SHOWN_REMINDER"];  
    if (!haveShownReminder)
{
    //show your alert

    //set it to 1
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"HAVE_SHOWN_REMINDER"];    
}
```

Comment: Isn’t the `registerDefaults:` extra?

Answer (score 2):

**3 simple lines**

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)applicationBlahBlah {
    if(![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"NOT_FIRST_TIME"] boolValue])
    {
        [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] autorelease] show];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"NOT_FIRST_TIME"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no issues in doing this but you can directly use bool for setting flag.

Comment: Easier realise that i'm working with NSNumber objects. Not some bool values

Answer (score 1):

As above solution should work in most cases, i would like to keep you aware on below as well at this point in time.

Apple document says: The NSUserDefaults class does not currently support per-host preferences. To do this, you must use the CFPreferences API. Ref [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

And a discussion on this [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/80851-nsuserdefaults-writing-to-machine-wide-preferences.html)