# is that possible to know my apps is first time run or not in xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios5, xcode4.3

i create an apps that i want to prompt an message for the user.. maybe using UIAlertview. After that, if the user run the apps for the second time, the alert won't prompt up anymore.

is that possible? honestly i don't have any idea about how to doing this.
Any idea? I search on STO, actually [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090541/how-to-show-popup-alert-view-when-apps-run-first-time), still confused.

what is NSUserDefaults? How can NSUserDefaults store this information? i mean this is my first time or second time.

thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To know what's NSUserDefaults, I suggest to take a look the [official doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

And of course you can use it to fulfill your goal.
You use a user default to store information about the current amount of runs in the app.

More or less like:

```
BOOL isRunMoreThanOnce = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isRunMoreThanOnce"];
if(!isRunMoreThanOnce){
    // Show the alert view
    // Then set the first run flag
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"isRunMoreThanOnce"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: hi.. thanks for your answer. i got it. i will mark your answer as correct answer since you are the first answer my question.. thanks.

Comment: hi, where should i put it? i mean the NSUserDefaults. at the appdelegate or at my view controller? because i try to put it at appdelegate, always give me run for the first time. thanks.

Comment: it shouldn't make this big difference where you put it. Just where you want to show the alert.

Comment: I forgot to put the "synchronize" statement, mayebe that was the problem. Try to update the code with it and let me know.

Comment: okay.. thanks for your answer. i already finish it.. thanks.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, U can save a value in NSUserDefault for the first time in your app & set it some other value once you open the app.

like

```
if(![[NSUserDefault standardUserDefault] objectforKey:@"AppOpenFirstTime"])
{
// App Open First time 
// Show Alert
[[NSUserDefault standardUserDefault] setObject:@"1" forKey:@"AppOpenFirstTime"]
}
```

Comment: hi.. thanks for your answer.. i will vote your answer.. thanks. :)

Comment: hi, where should i put it? i mean the NSUserDefaults. at the appdelegate or at my view controller? because i try to put it at appdelegate, always give me run for the first time. thanks.

Comment: If you want to show the alert to the user for the very first time than you can put that in your first viewcontroller which is getting displayed, in viewDidLoadMethod.

Comment: thanks for your answer.. i already solved it with your help and @Nicola Miotto.. thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can check if you stored some value in NSUserDefaults

```
NSString *flag = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"not_first_run"];
if (!flag) {
    //first run, do somethig
}
```

and then set it to some value

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"just any string" forKey:@"not_first_run"];
```

[NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is a key-value store saved between your application launches.

Comment: hi.. thanks for your answer.. i will vote your answer.. thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it exactly as cortez said in your link. NSUserDefaults is written to disc, and will be created and accessed from your app.

See this [link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/)

Comment: hi.. thanks for your answer.. i will vote your answer.. thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

First Time when your application launch at that time `boolForKey:@"AlreadyRan"` is `FALSE`. after that set it `TRUE`.

```
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"AlreadyRan"] ) 
 {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"AlreadyRan"];       
 }
```

> With the NSUserDefaults class, you can save settings and properties
>   related to application or user data.
>
> ```
> The objects will be saved in what is known as the iOS “defaults system”. 
> The iOS defaults system is available throughout all of the code in your app, and any data saved to the defaults system will persist through application sessions.This means that even if the user closes your application or reboots their phone, the saved data will still be available the next time they open the app!
> ```

Comment: hi.. thanks for your answer.. i will vote your answer.. thanks. :)